# Understanding UK Visa status

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I have applied for UK tourist visa from Finland. It is showing following status on the screen;

[image]

As it is red after the decision made and passback from consulate lines, I doubt it is rejected. But I am not sure. Can someone please tell me the meaning of this?

Comment: It's the VFS's site giving an 'unofficial' reading on your status, not UKVI's.  Did you get your passport back?

Comment: "passback" appears to be a new option in certain cases to return the passport while the application is still being processed.

Comment: It looks to me like this site is having some other issues. From here it looks like translations are not loaded correctly, the `tma_ukvi_uk_application_transferred_to_dmc` is a _key_ which is used to load the correct translation depending on the language of the site. Have you tried logging out, then back in and refreshing the page? This won't help with your visa status, but might make the labels make sense.

Comment: I dint get the passport back yet. I believe it'll take few more days to arrive. Yes, it looks like that site has some issue as it shows description as %s. Still red color doesn't seem to be due to any technical issue.

Comment: I am guessing that this means the VFS staff have not correctly updated their site with your status. Piss poor presentation also. What's 'tma' and why are the words connected with underscores like some noob developer's first project. My guess is that whoever is supposed to update the VFS's db screwed up or called in sick. Piss poor over all!

Comment: I applied for a visa in Helsinki and saw the same thing. It's just a buggy web site.

Comment: Can you change the language to Finnish or any other language to see if the placeholders are replaced by real text? If so, use Chrome to translate the web page

Comment: did you ever get the visa? I applied for a visa for my wife and it's the same deal, the passport is on its way back by DHL but there's no information about whether it was approved or not.

Comment: Yes we had got it.

Comment: "DMC" stands for the UK Government Decision Making Center. "VAC" stands for the Visa Application Centre. Ref: http://www.britchamdr.com/en/uk-visa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question...

> Can someone please tell me the meaning of this?

...is "**indeterminate**". They, i.e., the VFS, is attempting to adopt something like the 'Amazon model' where the customer gets lots of updates about their order. They present six different status markers which would normally follow the sequence from top to bottom.  The markers are "noob gibberish" which are either incomprehensible to the end user or require word-by-word scanning.

Incredible to relate, the strapline says "*...returned description %s...*"! Look at it in disbelief!

In your case, they show an illogical sequence with no explanation (and of course you came here for an answer and we'll do our best to help out). As I mentioned in comments, the my best guess is that the database person was out and somebody screwed it up.

Even if it were in sequence, those steps have little meaning to the end user, presumably "dmc" means "decision-making consulate", but what does it tell you? It's an amateur hack. Buggy.

What this amalgamates to is: indeterminate, **ignore it**, that system is not trustworthy. Your application is in the pipeline and you'll just have to brass it out.

Note: this site is *not* a UK government production. It's the courier's site and obviously outside of UKVI's tight quality control standards.

Comment: Those strings are placeholders, intended to be swapped out at runtime for either a local language translation for the logged in user, or a proper descriptive text updated by someone other than the programmer.  All it indicates is that the site has a technical issue, nothing more - even StackExchange has had this issue in the past - its not amateur, its just a technical issue.

Comment: @Moo your comment is well worth promoting to a full answer.  Your insight can prove valuable should similar questions arise. Consider adding a proper answer to the OP.

Comment: I disagree with @Moo. Presenting placeholders to end users is amateurish whether VFS does it or StackExchange does it. There are many things about StackExchange that could be done better from a technical point of view, such as the very rigid formatting.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan in that case, every single time there is an error or an issue with a website, then that is "amateurish" because it should not have happened - and that is simply not technically achievable even for massive websites such as this one or Facebook.

Comment: "UKVI's tight quality control standards": They may be tighter than this, but they're not that tight.  The online application for the EEA family permit was extremely confusing, not least because it used "you" to refer both to the applicant and the sponsor at different times.  It also asked whether the applicant and the sponsor "had any children" (presumably meaning "together") when the sponsor was one of the applicant's children.

Comment: What my main doubt was since the description due to any technical reason, bug on the site, or local settings problem, was not appearing and the decision made section was red, my visa could have been rejected. But, thank god, it is approved :)

Comment: Google results indicate that “DMC” is an acronym for “Decision-Making Centre”. Apparently the application goes there from the “VAC” (Visa Application Centre, where you provide your biometrics data and documents now) and back. The passport is sent from the VAC via snail mail to the applicant (that is what they told my girlfriend) or (perhaps in other countries) the applicant can fetch their passport (with or without the visa) at the VAC.

Answer (score 4):

Since it is obviously a software error, [as explained by Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76547/35890), I suggest you **use the contact mechanism on the site to report a problem and seek help about your visa status**.

If available, use a contact mechanism like "report a problem/request help with this site".  Otherwise, use a general one.  Include the above screenshot.

They might not respond, but then again they might, and that might mean getting information about your application slightly earlier.

At the very least, there is some hope that things will be fixed for future users.

Comment: +1, the OP could also send a screen shot to UKVI. They would take it seriously.

Comment: I tried to contact them they replied that decision has been made, you'll get your passport soon. They dint talk about this in detail :(

Comment: yup :), it was approved